# Why are certain functions permissible while others are not (from a security standpoint)?

Tags: security, permissions

You would think there must be some sort of logical convention or decision-making that leads to what is or is not permissible, followed by sanity checks against each functions' interactions for homogeniety; however, it feels like this isn't the case.  Take for example: the end user is able to read incoming SMS (if so configured) but not able to send outbound replies when in lock screen.  However, when connected to Android Auto, by default receiving an inbound SMS will trigger an automatic preset outbound reply, *regardless* of the device's lockstate, and is permitted to read the inbound SMS via TTS regardless of the preview configuration.  Why is there an assumption that the outbound transmission is any more or less secure in one case as opposed to the other, etc?